# CiviCRM 5.70.1 install on Drupal 10.2.3 - failure

Tags: drupal, installation

I am trying to install the latest CiviCRM on a fresh Drupal 10.2.3 install. This is on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS.

When I run the cv command (see below) to install CiviCRM, it is not installed and I receive the following error message:

```
TypeError: array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, bool given in /var/www/mysite/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/setup/src/Setup/DbUtil.php on line 13 

#0 /var/www/mysite/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/setup/src/Setup/DbUtil.php(13): array_map()
#1 phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Util/SetupCommandTrait.php(80): Civi\Setup\DbUtil::parseDsn()
#2 phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Command/CoreInstallCommand.php(47): Civi\Cv\Command\CoreInstallCommand->bootSetupSubsystem()
#3 phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Command/Command.php(127): Civi\Cv\Command\CoreInstallCommand->execute()
#4 phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(637): Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Command\Command->run()
#5 phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(190): Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRunCommand()
#6 phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Application.php(67): Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->doRun()
#7 phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/vendor/symfony/console/Application.php(101): Civi\Cv\Application->doRun()
#8 phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/src/Application.php(33): Cvphar\Symfony\Component\Console\Application->run()
#9 phar:///usr/local/bin/cv/bin/cv(28): Civi\Cv\Application::main()
#10 /usr/local/bin/cv(14): require('...')
#11 {main}
TypeError: array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) must be of type array, bool given in array_map() (line 13 of /var/www/mysite/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/setup/src/Setup/DbUtil.php).
```

To reproduce this error,

1. Do a fresh Drupal 10.2.3 install
2. Verify that Drupal is working
3. Resolve any remaining errors listed in Status Report
4. Attempt to install CiviCRM with the following:

```
cd /var/www/mysite.org
composer require civicrm/civicrm-{core,packages,drupal-8}
composer require civicrm/cli-tools

cv core:install --cms-base-url="https://mysite.org" --db="mysql://user:topsecretpassword@localhost:3306/mysqldatabasenameforcivicrm"
```

Here are the commands in and around line 13 of /var/www/mysite/vendor/civicrm/civicrm-core/setup/src/Setup/DbUtil.php

```
  1 <?php
  2 namespace Civi\Setup;
  3
  4 use Civi\Setup\Exception\SqlException;
  5
  6 class DbUtil {
  7
  8   /**
  9    * @param string $dsn
 10    * @return array
 11    */
 12   public static function parseDsn($dsn) {
 13     $parsed = array_map('urldecode', parse_url($dsn));
 14     // parse_url parses 'mysql://admin:secret@unix(/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)/otherdb' like:
 15     // [
 16     //   'host'   => 'unix(',
 17     //   'path'   => '/var/lib/mysql/mysql.sock)/otherdb',
 18     //   ...
 19     // ]
 20     if ($parsed['host'] == 'unix(') {
 21       preg_match('/(unix\(.*\))(\/(.+)?)?$/', $dsn, $matches);
 22       $server = $matches[1];
 23       $database = $matches[3] ?? NULL;
 24     }
 25     else {
 26       $server = self::encodeHostPort($parsed['host'], $parsed['port'] ?? NULL);
 27       $database = $parsed['path'] ? ltrim($parsed['path'], '/') : NULL;
 28     }
 ...
```

I also tried several things:

1. opening write permissions to

web/sites/default
web/sites/default/settings.php

in the event that cv required write access to these.

2. I tried running the cv command alternatively as the site administrator user and the root user.
3. I looked at the Drupal extensions list and CiviCRM Core is listed. I was confused by that because if the cv command was failing, then I would not expect that the CiviCRM Core would be available to be enabled. I tried it anyway and received a white screen with just the following message: "The website encountered an unexpected error. Try again later."
4. I have scoured the internet an do not find this DbUtil.php line 13 "TypeError: array_map(): Argument #2 ($array) ..." error mentioned.

Thank you for your assistance,

Joe

Comment: Does your password contain characters that might be causing the command line argument to be misinterpreted? It's saying it's failing to parse your db url.

Comment: Thank you Demerit!! My password contained special characters to keep it a strong password. I removed them, lowered the mysql validate_password.policy to not require special characters and tried again. The error above was replaced by another error message in white letters with a red background: "Access denied for user 'specialuser'@'localhost' to database 'mydb'"

Comment: If you run `SHOW GRANTS for 'specialuser'@'localhost'` in mysql does the user actually have access to `mydb`?

Comment: GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, RELOAD, REFERENCES, ALTER ON *.* TO `specialuser`@`localhost` WITH GRANT OPTION,  I believe the *.* indicates that has access to all databases.